# How can I determine which of two buttons is pressed by the user in the ABUnknownPersonViewController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uibutton

I have a button where if user press I am showing `ABUnknownPersonViewController`. Now the problem is there are two options **Create New Contact** & **Add To Existing Contact**. How can I determine which of the options is selected?

I need to know this because in my app, I am showing my contacts in another portion. Some times it causes my app to crash with the error:

> Shouldn't be trying to show more than one Add to Existing Contact people picker

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Assign tag value to the buttons and check the tag of the button clicked. Put condition according to the tag and show your views.

```
- (IBAction)contactsEdit_New:(id)sender 
{
    if ([addExitingBtn tag]==0)
    {
        // load ur view for exiting

    } 
    else  // here you can add if condition if required
    {
        // load view for creating new
    }


}
```

Hope this hepls.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you have 2 UIButtons?
Give each of them a tag and point them out to one method. If you're using IB just CTRL drag to your code (.m file).
Something like this:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
  switch (sender.tag) {
    case 0:
      // load create controller
      break;

    case 1:
      // load add controller
      break;

    default:
      break;
  }
}
```

You could also try and compare the text on the buttons titlelabel, though I don't really think that's good practice since the text on buttons can change during development.

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
  if([sender.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"create"]) {
    // load create controller
  } else if ([sender.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"add"]) {
    // load add controller
  }
}
```

You could also create 2 different methods for each button :)
This way you can avoid using tags since both buttons have their own method to answer to.

Good luck.